Is it possible for column-name of a DuckDB column to be a type other than string?
I think the answer to this question is "no", but I'd like to confirm.
Based on the syntax diagram provided in the documentation for CREATE TABLE, I guess that column-name can only accept a string-like identifier in CREATE TABLE table-name (column-name-0 COLTYPE-A, column-name-1 COL-TYPE-B)`.
But suppose I started with this data:
  types: varchar      date   integer
headers: "hello"     "date"  "value"
   data:    "a"   2024-JAN        0
   data:    "a"   2024-FEB        1

Then I might want to PIVOT it into the following:
  types: varchar   integer   integer
headers: "hello"  2024-JAN  2024-FEB
   data:     "a"         0         1

without destroying the DATE structure of the headers.
After all, perhaps later, I might want to UNPIVOT this data back into the "row-long" format, and it would be nice to not have to reparse the date from a string back into a DATE object?

convert it from date to string and back

Yes, the name is always a string and must match the identifier rules: https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/keywords_and_identifiers.html#identifiers

@FrankHeikens Thanks for the sanity check. Feel free to post that as an answer; I would be happy to accept it. I was thinking about this while commuting, and I think the best thing to do is to have a "dictionary" (in other words, another table) which allows one to convert from the string representation to a non-string representation of a column. I could post an answer that takes this approach, but I could also just create a separate, linked question and give you the points for this one.

duckdb is largely self-documenting and indeed by using describe duckdb_columns,
one can verify that column names must be of type VARCHAR.
Specifically, here are the first few lines from the output of describe duckdb_columns;:
┌──────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│       column_name        │ column_type │  null   │   key   │ default │  extra  │
│         varchar          │   varchar   │ varchar │ varchar │ varchar │ varchar │
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ database_name            │ VARCHAR     │ YES     │         │         │         │
│ database_oid             │ BIGINT      │ YES     │         │         │         │
│ schema_name              │ VARCHAR     │ YES     │         │         │         │
│ schema_oid               │ BIGINT      │ YES     │         │         │         │
│ table_name               │ VARCHAR     │ YES     │         │         │         │
│ table_oid                │ BIGINT      │ YES     │         │         │         │
│ column_name              │ VARCHAR     │ YES     │         │         │         │


So one would expect select 1 as '1'; to work, as indeed it does.
